# MySQL query can it be done better

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am currently doing the follow for the last 6 months but it seems like it could be done way better (less lines of code and possibly more optimized)

```
$monthones = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - 1, 1);
$monthonef = mktime(0, 0, 0-1, date("n"), 1);

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE type = '1' AND status = '1' AND (date >= '".$monthones."' AND date <= '".$monthonef."');";
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$monthone = $result->fetchColumn();

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE type = '3' AND status = '1' AND (date >= '".$monthones."' AND date <= '".$monthonef."');";
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$monthone2 = $result->fetchColumn();

$monthtwos = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - 2, 1);
$monthtwof = mktime(0, 0, 0-1, date("n") - 1, 1);

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE type = '1' AND status = '1' AND (date >= '".$monthtwos."' AND date <= '".$monthtwof."');";
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$monthtwo = $result->fetchColumn();

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE type = '3' AND status = '1' AND (date >= '".$monthtwos."' AND date <= '".$monthtwof."');";
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$monthtwo2 = $result->fetchColumn();
```

And I've got the same queries for rest 4 months. Any suggestions how I can improve this? I was thinking of combining the queries and start counting while looping the results? Or would that be worse?

Comment: probably belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: See **Section2 / What does Show your Schema Mean?** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) to help us to help you :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it would be more efficient to run *one* query against the database, one pass through the data.

For the date range conditions, rather than subtracting a second, and using a

```
<= last second of month
```

I prefer to use a pattern using

```
<  first second of following month
```

If the logic in the original code is correct for generating the "start" and "finish" boundaries, we only need seven boundary values, the first second of each month:

```
$month00 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - 0, 1);
$month01 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - 1, 1);
$month02 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - 2, 1);
$month03 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - 3, 1);
$month04 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - 4, 1);
$month05 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - 5, 1);
$month06 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n") - 6, 1);
```

And then the query can be something like this:

```
$query = "
SELECT SUM(u.type = '1' AND u.date >= '$month01' AND u.date < '$month00') AS monthone
     , SUM(u.type = '3' AND u.date >= '$month01' AND u.date < '$month00') AS monthone2

     , SUM(u.type = '1' AND u.date >= '$month02' AND u.date < '$month01') AS monthtwo
     , SUM(u.type = '3' AND u.date >= '$month02' AND u.date < '$month01') AS monthtwo2

     , ...
     , ...

     , SUM(u.type = '1' AND u.date >= '$month06' AND u.date < '$month05') AS monthsix
     , SUM(u.type = '3' AND u.date >= '$month06' AND u.date < '$month05') AS monthsix2

  FROM users u
 WHERE u.status = '1'
   AND u.type IN ('1','3')
   AND u.date >= '$month06'
   AND u.date  < '$month00'
";
```

The `...` would be replaced by repeating the expression patterns to return columns `monththree`/`monththree2`, `monthfour`/`monthfour2`, `monthfive`/`monthfive2`

Note that this uses MySQL shorthand, the expression inside the SUM() aggregate is evaluated to 1 (if the condition is TRUE) or a 0 (if the condition is FALSE) or NULL.

We would have to fetch the whole row to get all the counts. We'd have to ditch the `fetchColumn()` and use a `fetch()` instead.

```
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If we need the values in your scalar variables, so we don't have to change subsequent code:

```
$monthone  = $row['monthone'];
$monthone2 = $row['monthone2'];
$monthtwo  = $row['monthtwo'];
$monthtwo2 = $row['monthtwo2'];
...
...
$monthsix  = $row['monthsix'];
$monthsix2 = $row['monthsix2'];
```

Comment: WoW awesome reply works like a charm! Just a quick question if you don't mind. If I only had 2 queries to run (for example for just a single month) would it be better to do the above solution or run 2 queries with fetchColumn? Thanks!

Comment: I'd prefer to run just one query to get the two counts for a single month. One pass through the rows in the table. Let the database do the work. For non-trivial sets, the table should have appropriate indexes (which our query can make effective use of.)

Comment: As a compromise between the original pattern and this one, I'd at least get the two counts for a month with a single query. That would be running six queries instead of twelve (compared to the original.)

Comment: Great thank you very much for your help and time mate! I might have a similar question with multiple SUM() queries in the future which I can't seem to figure out with the above solution right now. :)

Comment: This same pattern of conditional aggregation can be used to get aggregates other than counts. To get a "total", you could do something like **`SUM(IF(boolean_condition, t.col_to_total, NULL)) AS tot_whatever`**. Or, an equivalent CASE expression.  In the query in my answer, I used MySQL shorthand, equivalent to the more ANSI standard compliant:  `SUM(CASE WHEN boolean_condition THEN 1 WHEN NOT boolean_condition THEN 0 ELSE NULL END)`

Comment: If the query getting that "total" is scanning the same rows that the query getting the "counts"... the expression to return the "total" could be included in the *same* query that gets the "counts". It is usually much more efficient to run one query than running multiple queries, making multiple round trips to and from the database, to scan the same rows over and over.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. I was having a ton of different queries and I am down to 3 from 25 or so. I am basically splitting them by the number of tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could return all the counts in a single query using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select count(case when type = '1' AND 
                  date >= '".$monthones."' AND date <= '".$monthonef."' then 1 end) cnt1,
       count(case when type = '3' AND 
                  date >= '".$monthones."' AND date <= '".$monthonef."' then 1 end) cnt2,
       count(case when type = '1' AND 
                  date >= '".$monthtwos."' AND date <= '".$monthtwof."' then 1 end) cnt3,
       count(case when type = '3' AND 
                  date >= '".$monthtwos."' AND date <= '".$monthtwof."' then 1 end) cnt4
from users 
where status = '1'
```

Comment: ... `and type in ('1','3') and date >= '$monthsixs' AND date < '$monthzeros'`

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work. I don't get the same results.

Comment: Maybe it's fetchColumn problem?

Comment: @J.Sm -- difficult to say without sample data and expected results.  I imagine this query should return the same results though, just 4 columns instead of a single column.  So yes, if you didn't alter your php code, then I could see how you would have an issue...

Comment: @sgeddes With the exact code I get '4' results for every single one of them. That's with using fetchColumn. Using fetch instead seems to work correctly. Is this OK?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using only one SQL query.
Please, try this:

```
select count(case when type= '1' then 1 end) type_one
     , count(case when type= '3' then 1 end) type_three
     , DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),'%Y-%m') month
 from users
where status = '1'
  and date between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
group by DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),'%Y-%m')
```

You can replace CURDATE() with a parameter.

Comment: Based on the query in the question, it looks like `date` column is probably  defined as an *integer* datatype, not a MySQL DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype.